# Outer Join / Union ?- t/sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I need help with a complex t/sql query for a special report I'm writing. 
I dont quite know how to articulate this problem; but I'll have a go:

Basicly, I have three tables as follows:

```
@PrimaryTable
  Key - Is unique and may or may not exist
  Description1 - Some field 
  Description2 - Some field which works as a heading, more on this later

@Subtable1
  KeyFK - is NOT unique, links to Key in primary table. May or may not exist. May also exist multiple times per Key
  Description - The field I want

@Subtable2 
 - Just like subtable1, but does not relate to subtable1 in any way
```

I want to join these tables to PrimaryTable as it would look with a UNION ALL, but without all the NULL values.

See this query for an example:

```
DECLARE @PrimaryTable AS table ("Key" int, Description1 varchar(32), Description2 varchar(32));        --Contains MAXIMUM one of each Key
DECLARE @Subtable_1 AS table ("KeyPK" int, SubDescription1 varchar(32));    --Can contain zero, one or more lines with same KeyPK
DECLARE @Subtable_2 AS table ("KeyPK" int, SubDescription2 varchar(32));    --Can contain zero, one or more lines with same KeyPK

INSERT INTO @PrimaryTable VALUES (1, 'Description', 'Heading');
INSERT INTO @PrimaryTable VALUES (2, 'Description', 'Heading');
INSERT INTO @PrimaryTable VALUES (3, 'Description', 'Heading');
INSERT INTO @PrimaryTable VALUES (5, 'Description', 'Heading');
INSERT INTO @PrimaryTable VALUES (6, 'Description', 'Heading');
INSERT INTO @PrimaryTable VALUES (7, 'Description', 'Heading');
INSERT INTO @PrimaryTable VALUES (8, 'Description', 'Heading');

INSERT INTO @Subtable_1 VALUES (1, 'Subdescription1_1');

INSERT INTO @Subtable_2 VALUES (2, 'Subdescription2_1');

INSERT INTO @Subtable_1 VALUES (3, 'Subdescription1_1');
INSERT INTO @Subtable_2 VALUES (3, 'Subdescription2_1');

INSERT INTO @Subtable_1 VALUES (4, 'Subdescription1_1');
INSERT INTO @Subtable_2 VALUES (4, 'Subdescription2_1');
INSERT INTO @Subtable_2 VALUES (4, 'Subdescription2_2');

INSERT INTO @Subtable_1 VALUES (5, 'Subdescription1_1');
INSERT INTO @Subtable_1 VALUES (5, 'Subdescription1_2');
INSERT INTO @Subtable_2 VALUES (5, 'Subdescription2_1');

INSERT INTO @Subtable_1 VALUES (6, 'Subdescription1_1');
INSERT INTO @Subtable_2 VALUES (6, 'Subdescription2_1');
INSERT INTO @Subtable_2 VALUES (6, 'Subdescription2_2');

INSERT INTO @Subtable_1 VALUES (7, 'Subdescription1_1');
INSERT INTO @Subtable_1 VALUES (7, 'Subdescription1_2');
```

I want the result to look as following:

```
/*
Key Description1    Description2    Subdescription1     Subdescription2
_________________________________________________________________________
1   Description     Heading         ''                  ''
1   Description     ''              Subdescription1_1   NULL

2   Description     Heading         ''                  ''
2   Description     ''              NULL                Subdescription2_1

3   Description     Heading         ''                  ''
3   Description     ''              Subdescription1_1   Subdescription2_1

5   Description     Heading         ''                  ''
5   Description     ''              Subdescription1_1   Subdescription2_1
5   Description     ''              Subdescription1_2   NULL

6   Description     Heading         ''                  ''
6   Description     ''              Subdescription1_1   Subdescription2_1
6   Description     ''              NULL                Subdescription2_2

7   Description     Heading         ''                  ''
7   Description     ''              Subdescription1_1   NULL
7   Description     ''              Subdescription1_2   NULL

8   Description     Heading         ''                  ''
*/
```

The Heading line with the empty descriptions is no problem; can easily be done using a union afterwards, but I dont know how to join these tables like this - Does anyone know how this could be done?

Edit:
I should have explained the report from the start:
I'm working on a very great DB-structure, but I have a very odd report requirement.

PrimaryTable is an actual table, which the report asks on
Subtable1 is table which explains different parts of primary table, this is real info.
Subtable2 is not a table, but a contract(a field from PrimaryTable) broken down to one row pr. line.

The report then wants all info from Primary table as a heading including some subtotals. Then there is a fold down option, which opens to one row pr. subtable2 description / line in contract. The amount of lines pr Key simply shows the length of each fold down.

As much as posible will be done by SQL for report answering times. - This will be a stored procedure which will generate a fast answering solution-based table

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you want something like this:

```
SELECT key, description1, description2, '', ''
FROM PrimaryTable
UNION
SELECT distinct p.description1, '', s1.subdescription1, s2.subdescription2
FROM PrimaryTable as p
LEFT JOIN Subtable1 as s1
ON p.key = s1.key
LEFT JOIN Subtable2 as s2
ON p.key = s2.key
```

I will also say that it looks like you have a pretty strange database structure.  Is there any reason you have two "subdescription" tables?

Comment: Wow thank you, that is basicly exactly what i was looking for; somehow the word distinct did not come to my mind...

The DB-structure I'm working on is actually quite good, it is the report which doesn't make sence. 
I should have explained the report from the start; question will be updated now.

Comment: EDIT:
I've just proofread the queries, and this one still gives me the same error, see key = 5 and key = 6, I need NULL's instead of 'Subdescription2_1' and 'Subdescription1_2' accordingly

Comment: Interesting.  Can you explain the logic that you are using to determine that `Subdescription1_2  -  NULL` must be returned for key `5`?

Comment: I'm sorry; once again I was to unclear,
subdescription2: Return NULL instead of Subdescription 2_2 WHERE Key = 5

Subdescription1:Return NULL instead o Subdescription 1_2 WHERE Key = 6
The reason that this field should Return NULL is because:
When key = 5, There are two lines in Subtable1, and one line in Subtable2
Therefore The amount of lines where Key = 5 in the result is 3 (2[The higher amount of lines] + the one with header)
After this amount of lines is found, it should only add each of the information from the subtable once; eg. returning the values as result shows in original question.

Comment: The first SELECT should assign aliases to the empty columns, and the second one is missing the `key` column, and the `key` column should be delimited everywhere. Other than that, this must work correctly except for the cases when both subtables have more than one item for the same `key` (you would get duplicates then).

Comment: Yes I would, but I don't want these duplicates, many of the items I'm trying to view will have more than one item in each subtable,

Answer (score 0):

This is close to your expected results (double-check where Key = 6 and also 8):

```
SELECT "Key", 
       P1.Description1, '' AS Description2, 
       S1.SubDescription1, S2.SubDescription2
  FROM @PrimaryTable AS P1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN @Subtable_1 AS S1
          ON P1."Key" = S1."KeyPK"
       LEFT OUTER JOIN @Subtable_2 AS S2
          ON P1."Key" = S2."KeyPK"
UNION
SELECT "Key", 
       P1.Description1, P1.Description2, 
       '' AS SubDescription1, '' AS SubDescription2
  FROM @PrimaryTable AS P1
 ORDER 
    BY "Key", Description2 DESC;
```